# Is there a way to simulate particle stopping stochastically, from a known $dE/dx$ curve?

Tags: particle-physics, simulations, stochastic-processes, ionization-energy, cosmic-rays

I want to make a simulation of the stopping of Muons in liquid water that, instead of considering they lost exactly the amount of energy predicted by the $dE/dx$ curve at each iteration, sorts an amount of energy loss according to an energy loss distribution W(E), to make it more probabilistic.

And I've found some information about said energy loss distribution from [this link](https://meroli.web.cern.ch/lecture_StragglingFunction.html), but it only covers ionization loss and considering several simplifications.

I've found nothing about that distribution for the highest energy portion of dE/dx where bremsstrahlung dominates the energy loss.

Also, I don't know if I have all data I'd need even for the ionization part, such as the maximum energy transferable in a single collision, Emax.

What I have for Muons in liquid water is all the [info](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/AtomicNuclearProperties/HTML/water_liquid.html) from the Particle Data Group (the dE/dx curves are in the bottom of that page).

But I'm not sure if I have information enough to calculate the energy loss distribution W(E) from that.

Do any of you know how I could do that?

Apart from, of course, making a full-scale physical simulation using Geant4.

Thanks!

Comment: You might look into the info on SRIM.